# TypeScript not getting compiled in CMD

Tags: typescript

.TS file is not getting compiled

## main.ts file

```
function doSomething() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }

    console.log('finally' + i);
}

 doSomething();
```

CMD Command Compile Code

```
C:\ts-testfolder>tsc main.ts
```

The issue is my main.ts file is not getting compiled whereas main.js is getting compiled see below:

```
C:\ts-hello>node main.js
0
1
2
3
4
finally5
```

Please see CMD print screen below:

[image]

Comment: `tsc` is the *compiler*; it *compiles*, it doesn't start an interactive environment like `node` does. Try `ts-node` if you want a TypeScript REPL.

Comment: In other words, `tsc` is _creating_ main.js.